# os.path.join and sqlite not playing well together

Tags: python, sqlite, os.path

Python 2.7 (Windows)

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.DiskLocation, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            print path #check it's what we think it is
            self.cur.execute("SELECT * from myTable WHERE Path = ?", (path))
```

Yields this...

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 54 supplied.

I was really confused as to what the 54 supplied bindings are, until I realised that my path variable is 54 characters. But why is sqlite interpreting it as a long list of characters rather than a string, and how do I stop it doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `execute` is a *sequence*.

You wrote `(path)`, but those are just regular parentheses, so that's equivalent to `path`.  Strings are sequences of their characters, thus Python is dutifully passing along all 54 characters in the sequence you provided.

What you want is `(path,)`, which is a tuple of 1 element.

Tuples are created with commas, **not** parentheses.

If this is confusing you could just use `[path]`; a list is fine here too.  :)

Comment: A tuple of one element needs a comma... not the most intuitive thing ever but makes sense given the alternative I suppose!